# MATE menu is missing

Tags: mate

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed MATE using `apt-get install mate-desktop-environment` (and before that, I added needed repositories from mate official website). Everything worked fine. However, when I started a MATE session, it looked like this:

[image]

How can I get the panels/menus? As seen here:

[image]

Comment: Double check that you have the necessary packages installed: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-extras`

Comment: You never responded so I am assuming the problem was fixed?

Comment: @Seth I've noticed the packages you suggest to install are different from those suggested in [the one answer posted](http://askubuntu.com/a/511113/22949). Since your comment really does answer the question (or at least may fix this for other people with a problem that presents exactly the same), you might consider posting it or something like it as an answer.

Comment: I don't have steps to reproduce but I did have the same issue and the 1 answer fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. I belive it was caused by conflicting config files from a not-yet-uninstalled Maté 1.6 and the recently installed Maté 1.8 (the one rule I forgot to follow).

The solution, as I recall it (though this was around a year ago), was something along the lines of:

```
sudo apt-get purge mate-*

sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

Along with whichever additional items  you wanted to install, like mate-desktop-environment-extras.

After that, everything worked fine. As I said, this was a year ago, but I have a friend that's having the same problem and has called me in to fix it. I'll come back with my final command sequence.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I installed the meta package ubuntu-mate-desktop after the purge command.